# Regular Expression return Customize String

Tags: regex

I am learning Regular Expression, I have a string like

```
grafana-stage.apps.mt-t1.cdc2.gkp.testdatabase.net:443
```

And I want the result only give me `mt-t1.cdc2`

I tried `(.*)-.*`, but it did not result in what I want. Has anyone a solution for this problem?

Again, thank you so much for your help .

Comment: Not enough details, and I also think that you're trying to get us do your work.

Comment: Check out https://regex101.com/ This usually helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you avemaet.  I just want to see how to only capturing the middle part of the string. I was playing on this website. but when I try (.*-.*), it still give me the first part of the string.

Comment: Try `\.([^.-]+-[^.]+\.[^.]+)`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/J4V2lo/2), the result is in Group 1.

Comment: What do you need to capture? 3rd and 4th domain labels from the start, 4th and 5th from the end, second that contains a dash plus the one following? There are so many possibilities. Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are so many expressions that you can design for returning `mt-t1.cdc2`, for instance the following one,

```
^[a-z]+-[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.([a-z]+-[a-z0-9]+\.[^.]+)\.[a-z.]+:[0-9]{3}$
```

would do that using the capturing group:

```
([a-z]+-[a-z0-9]+\.[^.]+)
```

#### DEMO

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Yl4pm/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### Test

```js
const regex = /^[a-z]+-[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.([a-z]+-[a-z0-9]+\.[^.]+)\.[a-z.]+:[0-9]{3}$/gm;
const str = `grafana-stage.apps.mt-t1.cdc2.gkp.testdatabase.net:443`;
const subst = `$1`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]